# Couldn't find User with 'id'=show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

a Rails/Devise Question for you today. I'm working on user profiles for a site and I am hitting this error

## ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /users/show

#### Couldn't find User with 'id'=show

---

Not sure exactly what's happening as I haven't really run into anything like this before. Here are some necessary files to take a look at-

---

*users_controller.rb*:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_bookmarks = @user.bookmarks
    @liked_bookmarks = @user.likes
  end

  def update
    if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "User information updated"
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Invalid user information"
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar)
  end
end
```

---

*routes.rb*:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:show, :update]

  post :incoming, to: 'incoming#create'

  resources :topics do
    resources :bookmarks, except: [:index]
  end

  resources :bookmarks, except: [:index] do
    resources :likes, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

---

*user.rb*:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  has_many :topics, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bookmarks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true

  def admin?
    role == 'admin'
  end

  def moderator?
    role == 'moderator'
  end

  def member?
    role == 'member'
  end

  def liked(bookmark)
    likes.where(bookmark_id: bookmark.id).first
  end
end
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `show` action depends on looking up an `id`. Since you're hitting the URL `/users/show`, it assumes you're trying to look up a user with `id` of `show`. Instead, you should be going to a url like `/users/1` to trigger the `show` action.

[The Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) has a section that specifies `GET /photos/:id` maps to `photos#show`.